# middleware('auth') not protecting page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created a post creation page that should be available only to logged in users using the code below for my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\StorePost ;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
public function __construst(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
//
public function index()
{
    # code...
    $posts = Post::latest()->get();
    return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
}
public function show(Post $post)
{
    # code...
    return view('posts.show',compact('post'));
}
public function create()
{
    # code...
    return view('posts.create');
}
public function store(StorePost $request)
{
    # code...
    $validated = $request->validated();
    Post::create(request(['title','body']));
    return redirect('/');
}
}
```

**web.php file**

```
<?php
 Route::get('/','PostController@index')->name('home');
 Route::get('/posts/create','PostController@create');
 Route::post('/posts','PostController@store');
 Route::get('/posts/{post}','PostController@show');
 Route::get('/tasks','TasksController@index');
 Route::get('/tasks/{tasks}', 'TasksController@show'); 
 Route::post('/posts/{post}/comment','CommentController@store');
 Route::get('/register','RegistrationsController@create');
 Route::post('/register','RegistrationsController@store');
 Route::get('/login','SessionsController@create');
 Route::get('/logout','SessionsController@destroy');
```

The problem i'm facing is that anyone can visit the posts creation page which should not be so

Comment: You have a typo in your constructor name. Should be `__construct()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mozammil mentioned, your function called `__construst()` is not a constructor.  It is just a function called `__construst`.  The way the Middleware works in the Controller like this, is you must add the middleware in the constructor which is a specific type of function that must be named `__construct`.

If you name it anything else, it will not be called when the object is created and the middleware will never be executed.